# How can I add timestamp into my table when I use Write-DbaDbTableData?

Tags: sql-server, timestamp, dbatools

I am trying to use one table to store the SQL server disk space checking data by dbatools:

```
$allservers_PRD | Get-DbaDiskSpace | Write-DbaDbTableData -SqlInstance MySQL2019 -Database SQL_DBA_TASK -Table SQL_DISK_SPACE -AutoCreateTable
```

How can I add timestamps (what is the checking time) into my table rows as addition column when I use it?

Many thanks,

Comment: Thank you very much, that works fine!

Comment: Added it as an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I was arranging a similar setup in the past, I did the following:

1. Use `-AutoCreateTable` to generate the basic schema for any commands I wanted to write to the database
2. Modify the tables to use better data types + added a column with a default `GETDATE()` value
3. Pipe any results into the newly modified tables.

This is also helpful since any updates to the command output will break due to schema differences and force you to adjust the code and table as needed.